# ASTRO framework how to use variables directly in imports

Tags: astrojs

I creeated multiple template placed in components, now depending on configuration I need local dynamic template.

Hardcoded data:

```
import Content from "../../components/minimal/Content/Content.astro";
```

now I try use:

```
import Content from "../../components/" + config.template + "/Content/Content.astro";
```

or

```
import Content from `../../components/${config.template}/Content/Content.astro`;
```

or

```
const contentPath = "../../components/" + config.template + "/Content/Content.astro";
const Content = import(contentPath);
```

but not work anything. Each error related to syntax etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import):

```js
const Content = (await import(`../../components/${config.template}/Content/Content.astro`)).default;
```

But depending on the details, vite (and by extension astro) [might not support it](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features#dynamic-import). In that case you'd have to import all the files, then switch at runtime between them.

Comment: This not work ;( now i try very different way example let Content;

async function importComponent() {
  try {
    const module = await import("../../components/minimal/Content/Content.astro");
    Content = module.default;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error importing Content component:", error);
  }
}

(async () => {
  await importComponent();
})();  but  Unable to render Content because it is undefined!  or  null.

Comment: For your code I get An error occurred.
Unexpected "nst"